# Module cpp could not be loaded in qbs

Tags: c++, qt, clang, qbs

Im trying to compile my project using the `clang` compiler with Qbs on `Windows 10 x64`. I configured the tool using the QtCreator interface, and the error `Module cpp could not be loaded` appeared.

This is my configuration:

[image]

What is happening?

Comment: Qbs is NOT an acronym, please do not propagate that ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I didn't know. @JakePetroules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message appears because no matching cpp module backend was found for the combination of clang toolchain and Windows target. I think the only compilers currently supported for Windows are MSVC and mingw.
Do you actually intend to create Windows binaries with clang?

Comment: Yes, I intend to. But I would have to create the backend for the clang compiler?

Comment: I suggest you create a task for this at bugreports.qt.io. I suppose one interesting question here is whether to implement the backend as a specialization of the generic GCC support (like we do with clang for Unix targets) or as a specialization of the MSVC support (via clang-cl).